# SDK 3.1 iOS 6 - Publish Permissions after Login and after removal of permission from Facebook App Settings

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

The following scenario is causing me some trouble.

The flow goes like this:

1. Login with Facebook and request basic read permissions
2. User takes action in app which requests Publish permissions
3. User says YES to publish permissions
4. User then goes to Facebook App, then app settings for our App and removes Publish permissions
5. User then goes back into our App and attempts to Publish a story
6. Facebook iOS SDK gives no indication that the permission was denied, in fact it returns that this permission has been granted. However, when querying /permissions in the graph API that permission is unavailable.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: In step 6 - when and where are you determining that the permission was granted? If it's at grant time, this is correct - that the user can subsequently change the permission set is expected, and there's no notification to your app's code that this took place - if a call fails and it may be because the permissions were revoked, a call to /me/permissions will confirm

Comment: I query /me/permissions as soon as I have a valid access token and almost every time the user takes an action with in the app to interact with Facebook.  The issue is when I make a call to reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions: or openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions: and they include the revoked permission, they succeed with no error.

Comment: OK, that sounds like it could be a bug then...

Comment: Let me know if you need any more info to reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: You should file it in the bug tracker with detailed repro steps - i don't work on the team that does bug repro and triage and can't take a stackoverflow question as a bug report